# Inserting data from Tkinter to Sqlite3 - sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Many people have posted about this error, but I can't figure it out.

This is a picture of my Tkinter GUI:
[image]

When the user clicks Save, I want the 'Campaign' entry to be the name of the database, and then I want the 'Workers' entries to be added to a table called (workers).

I think the problem is when I try to add the information to the table with a `for loop` and `c.execute("insert into workersNames (workers)", element)` although, this could just be one of the problems.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import sqlite3

class Research(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        # CAMPAIGN 
        campFrame = Frame(self)
        campFrame.pack(fill=X)

        campLbl = Label(campFrame, text="Campaign: ", width=8)
        campLbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        campEntry = Entry(campFrame)
        campEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.campStr = tk.StringVar()


        # CITY
        cityFrame = Frame(self)
        cityFrame.pack(fill=X)

        cityLbl = Label(cityFrame, text="City: ", width=8)
        cityLbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=8)

        cityEntry = Entry(cityFrame)
        cityEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.cityStr = tk.StringVar()


        # PROVINCE
        provFrame = Frame(self)
        provFrame.pack(fill=X)

        provLbl = Label(provFrame, text="Province: ", width=8)
        provLbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=8)

        provEntry = Entry(provFrame)
        provEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.provStr = tk.StringVar()


        # WORKERS
        workersFrame = Frame(self)
        workersFrame.pack(fill=X)

        workersLbl = Label(workersFrame, text="Workers: ", width=8)
        workersLbl.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        workersEntry1 = Entry(workersFrame)
        workersEntry1.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.workersStr1 = tk.StringVar()


        workersEntry2 = Entry(workersFrame)
        workersEntry2.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.workersStr2 = tk.StringVar()


        workersEntry3 = Entry(workersFrame)
        workersEntry3.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.workersStr3 = tk.StringVar()


        # SAVE
        saveFrame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        saveFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        saveButton = Button(self, text="Save", command = self.SaveDetails)
        saveButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)


    def SaveDetails(self):
        # Create Database
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.campStr.get() + ".db")
        c = conn.cursor()

        # Create Table - workersNames
        c.execute('''create table if not exists workersNames(
            workers text)''')
        conn.commit()

        # Add data to table
        names = [self.workersStr1.get(), self.workersStr2.get(), self.workersStr3.get()]

        for element in names:
            c.execute("insert into workersNames (workers)", element)
        conn.commit()

        c.close() 
        conn.close()



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300+300+300")
    app = Research(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your `insert` statement doesn't say anything about what to insert. See the [insert statement docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: @user2357112 I added `values` so it looks like this `   c.execute("insert into workersNames values (workers)", element)` but now the error is `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: workers` but I thought the column was created in the line where I create the table?  I'm using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120474/save-button-with-python-tkinter-sqlite) as a model for my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert the workers into the database, use:

```
c.execute("insert into workersNames (workers) values (?)", (element,))
```

I realized you have lots of `self.xx = tk.StringVar()`s that were not connected to any tkinter widget. Therefore, you get an empty string when you call `sef.xx.get()`. I removed the `tk.StringVar()`s to make the code shorter for testing and used the `get()` method on the tkinter entries to get their content.

Hence:

```
names = [self.workersStr1.get(), self.workersStr2.get(), self.workersStr3.get()]
```

became:

```
names = [self.workersEntry1.get(), self.workersEntry2.get(), self.workersEntry3.get()]
```

Notice I changed all the entries into class attributes using the `self` keyword.

Here is the full code, you can go through and see the changes:

```
#import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import *
#from tkinter.ttk import *
#import sqlite3

import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import sqlite3

class Research(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        # CAMPAIGN 
        campFrame = Frame(self)
        campFrame.pack(fill=X)

        campLbl = Label(campFrame, text="Campaign: ", width=8)
        campLbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.campEntry = Entry(campFrame)
        self.campEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)


        # CITY
        cityFrame = Frame(self)
        cityFrame.pack(fill=X)

        cityLbl = Label(cityFrame, text="City: ", width=8)
        cityLbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=8)

        cityEntry = Entry(cityFrame)
        cityEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)


        # PROVINCE
        provFrame = Frame(self)
        provFrame.pack(fill=X)

        provLbl = Label(provFrame, text="Province: ", width=8)
        provLbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=8)

        provEntry = Entry(provFrame)
        provEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)


        # WORKERS
        workersFrame = Frame(self)
        workersFrame.pack(fill=X)

        workersLbl = Label(workersFrame, text="Workers: ", width=8)
        workersLbl.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        self.workersEntry1 = Entry(workersFrame)
        self.workersEntry1.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)


        self.workersEntry2 = Entry(workersFrame)
        self.workersEntry2.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)


        self.workersEntry3 = Entry(workersFrame)
        self.workersEntry3.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)


        # SAVE
        saveFrame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        saveFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        saveButton = Button(self, text="Save", command = self.SaveDetails)
        saveButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)


    def SaveDetails(self):
        # Create Database
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.campEntry.get() + ".db")
        c = conn.cursor()

        # Create Table - workersNames
        c.execute('''create table if not exists workersNames(
            workers text)''')
        conn.commit()

        # Add data to table
        names = [self.workersEntry1.get(), self.workersEntry2.get(), self.workersEntry3.get()]

        for element in names:
            c.execute("insert into workersNames (workers) values (?)", (element,))
        conn.commit()

        c.close() 
        conn.close()



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300+300+300")
    app = Research(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**This produces the following results:**

[image]

[image]

I hope it helps.